# Will MySQL table with 250 columns will cause performance issue?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have an application which is usually containing more than 220 tables overall which is creating problems while fetching data for reporting.
User need to join so many tables to get data.
I decided to make a new horizontal database where all required data of entity will be in single row.
Which is resulting in more than 250 columns in single table.
My question here is user will typically select any of 5 or 10 columns for table in single report.
Will this kind of table will create performance issue ?

Comment: It will almost certainly violate 3NF badly, which will give you problems far beyond pjust erformance.

Comment: What is the % of read vs write query in your database ?
how frequently your user will view report ? Also suggesting not to create tables like this.

Comment: As mentioned, lots of tables and/or lots of columns are symptoms of poor schema design. So maybe start by describing what you're actually trying to model.

Comment: @arjun gowda , we do data writing after every four hours using spark job to our reporting schema. user will be accessing through out the day and please note that my table have minimum data of 1M  row

Comment: @strawberry ,if you see my problem statement we are creating a new database out of our application database for reporting purpose so report query will not hamper my application performance, and that is why we decided to merge many table to one table horizontally so user can fetch it quickly.

Comment: I see no logic in any of that

Comment: @arjun update your question with SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Answer (score 4):

A million, even a billion, *rows* is not a problem for a database.

220 tables involved in a single query is a problem.

250 columns in a single table is a problem.

Compromise.  Move groups of columns into a separate table.  Base the grouping on what columns are fetched together, or what columns are often `NULL`, or other logical criteria.

You can "hide" the structure from users by creating `VIEWs` that stitch the tables back together just for the query.  But, beware, having a `VIEW` with 250 columns will probably recreate the ills that you got rid of.

If you want to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss concrete columns and datatypes.

Oh, there are ways (`SET` or `INT`) to combine lots of boolean flags (if that is what is causing so many columns).

**Need more info**

Please use concrete column names and describe the application...

Some applications need lots of random info, and the table becomes a sparse matrix.  Example: description of products for sale.  Solution:  Throw the random info in a JSON string.

Some schemas are misdesigned by trying to put arrays across columns.  Example: Phones -- work + cell + home + fax + etc.  Solution:  Put them in a separate table; that is use multiple rows, not multiple columns.

Some columns don't need to be separate.  Example:  Address line 1 + line 2 + apartment number + city + province + region + country + postal code + continent.  Solution:  have a single text column for the mailing address.

It's hard to answer your vague question when there are many possible directions to go.

Comment: Hi @rick james, i want add few details that we created new schema with just 15 table out of 220 table for reporting purpose so number of column have been increased immensely but here user will select 10 or 20 columns out of table. do you still see this design as problem ?

Comment: @arjun - See my added paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

It dependent on what kind of data you store in each column.

First you have to check what is the purpose of each column and check if there is any possibility to partition them as separate or cluster table.